# Loop over pages when requesting API

Tags: javascript, node.js

I request an API and I have to loop over the different 'pages' (nearly 5000 'pages') using start_page and count attributes. I would like to store fetched data into a mySQL database.
How I can do to loop over the 'pages' and store data into the database synchronously?
I'm a newbie with promises and other asynchronous techniques.

Thanks for your help!

The loop looks like:

```
for (var i = Math.floor(body.pagination.total_result / body.pagination.items_per_page); i >= 0; i--) {
    listOfPromises.push(
        new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            request(schedulesURL + 'start_page=' + i + '&count=' + _COUNT, { json: true }, function(err, response, body) {
                if (err) { 
                    console.log('Erreur et i = ' + i);
                    reject(err);
                } else { 
                    //On résoud la promesse :
                    resolve(data);
                }
            })
        }));
    }
```

And I created a recursive function like that:

```
// Recursive function
function handlePromises(promises, cb, data = {
    dataSchedules: new Array(),
    dataExceptions: new Array()
}) {
    // If there is no more promises
    // break the function
    if (promises.length == 0) {
        cb(data);
    } else {
        // Shift remove the first elemn in array
        // and remove it from the array
        let promise = promises.shift()
        promise.then((promiseData) => {
            // do what you want with data
            return handlePromises(promises, cb, data)
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] and a little bit of a look into what you've tried so far?

Comment: Can you provide a snippet on what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I think you need:

```
async function init() {
    for (var i = Math.floor(body.pagination.total_result / body.pagination.items_per_page); i >= 0; i--) {

        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            request(schedulesURL + 'start_page=' + i + '&count=' + _COUNT, { json: true }, function(err, response, body) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Erreur et i = ' + i);
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    //On résoud la promesse :
                    resolve(data);
                }
        })
    });
}


init();
```